# Accelerometer X/Y/Z "high events"

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, mems

I'm looking at this accelerometer [LIS3DH](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00274221.pdf) and the datasheet says that it could enable interrupt generation on X/Y/Z "high" or "low" events. What do these events actually mean? When are "high events" generated? For X high events, are they generated when the sensor increases w.r.t. the X axis? Are these events indications of direction of movement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manufacturers' Data sheets for devices are often supplemented by their Application Notes.

There are a bunch of application notes on the [LIS3DH page](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM89/SC444/PF250725) under the "Design Resources" tab.

One of those is [AN3308: LIS3DH: MEMS digital output motion sensor ultra low-power high performance 3-axis “nano” accelerometer](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00290365.pdf)

It describes the features of the device. For example, in Section "6.2 Threshold", it explains how to set an acceleration threshold for an acceleration-triggered event. SImilarly "6.3. Free-fall and wake-up interrupts" explains how to define the type of event the LIS3DH should trigger.

AFAICT, depending on the selected mode, the event could be triggered by either an acceleration exceeding a threshold, and so could be directions of movement, or when the device is orientated in a particular way.

Edit:
Based on:

> *5 Interrupt generation*
>   The LIS3DH interrupts signal can behave as free-fall, wake-up, 6D and
>   4D orientation detection, and click detection. Those signals can be
>   driven to the two interrupt pins (INT1 and INT2).
>
> *6 Inertial interrupt*
>   The LIS3DH can provide two inertial interrupt
>   signals and offers several possibilities to personalize those signals ...

My interpretation is interrupts are intended to wake up the 'driving' MCU.

Comment: Thanks. Is the "inertial interrupt" actually meant to wake up the accelerometer itself or the MCU driving it?